# OnTouchListener: Swiping across the screen

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-activity, swipe

Please have a look at the following code. I am ONLY posting the important sections of the code.

**activity_game.xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/fullView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".Game" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numberOfQuestionsLeft"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="TextView" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**Game.java**

```
public class Game extends Activity {



    private View fullView;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        fullView = (View)findViewById(R.id.fullView);
        fullView.setOnTouchListener(imageViewSwiped);



    }


 OnTouchListener imageViewSwiped = new OnSwipeTouchListener()
    {
         public boolean onSwipeRight() 
         {
            //code removed
         }

          public boolean onSwipeLeft() 
          {
             //code removed
                return true;
          }

          public boolean onSwipeBottom()
          {
              //code removed
              return true;
          }


    };
}
```

**OnSwipTouchListener.java**

Note - I do not own this class of the code. It is written by another SO member.

```
     package game.Game;
        import android.view.GestureDetector;
        import android.view.GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener;
        import android.view.MotionEvent;
        import android.view.View;
        import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;

        public class OnSwipeTouchListener implements OnTouchListener {

            private final GestureDetector gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(new GestureListener());

            public boolean onTouch(final View v, final MotionEvent event) {
                gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
return true;
            }

            private final class GestureListener extends SimpleOnGestureListener {

                private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD = 100;
                private static final int SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD = 100;

                @Override
                public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                    return super.onDown(e);
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                    boolean result = false;
                    try {
                        float diffY = e2.getY() - e1.getY();
                        float diffX = e2.getX() - e1.getX();
                        if (Math.abs(diffX) > Math.abs(diffY)) {
                            if (Math.abs(diffX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                                if (diffX > 0) {
                                    result = onSwipeRight();
                                } else {
                                    result = onSwipeLeft();
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (Math.abs(diffY) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD && Math.abs(velocityY) > SWIPE_VELOCITY_THRESHOLD) {
                                if (diffY > 0) {
                                    result = onSwipeBottom();
                                } else {
                                    result = onSwipeTop();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (Exception exception) {
                        exception.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    return result;
                }
            }

            public boolean onSwipeRight() {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onSwipeLeft() {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onSwipeTop() {
                return false;
            }

            public boolean onSwipeBottom() {
                return false;
            }
        }
```

This code is set where I can touch across the activity and swipe. But, there is a problem. I noticed I need to swipe a blank space in the activity where no buttons, images, text boxes etc in order for this to work. But this is not what I need. Even the user touch on buttons and swipe left,right or down it should work. How should I make it that way?

Comment: OK, why am I getting downvotes? Comment please. Before that, read the question anyway

Comment: no one knows the answers?